# Yii2:- update record using update query for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to make update query using Yii2 for mongodb. I make following query:

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('usermaster');
       $arrUpdate = [ 
            'firstName' => $fname,
            'lastName' => $lname,
            'email' => $email,
            'is_visible' => $isvisibleUser,
            'phoneNumber' => $phone,
            'userName' => $uname,   
            ];
   $collection->update(['_id = 55a4957sd88423d10ea7c07d'],$arrUpdate);
```

But it shows follwoing error in firebug.

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/yii2angularseedmaster/frontend/web/category/corporateupdate?corpUserid=55a4957sd88423d10ea7c07d"
```

My insert query works perfectly but update query does not works.

Please tell me what is wrong in my query.

Comment: `['_id = 55a4957sd88423d10ea7c07d']` is wrong, it should be more like the second param plus that needs a MongoId wrapper

Comment: @Sammaye :- yes right. now i used $collection->update(['_id' => $id],$arrUpdate); and it works. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$collection->update(['_id' => $id],$arrUpdate);

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('usermaster');
       $arrUpdate = [ 
            'firstName' => $fname,
            'lastName' => $lname,
            'email' => $email,
            'is_visible' => $isvisibleUser,
            'phoneNumber' => $phone,
            'userName' => $uname,   
            ];
   $collection->update(['_id' => $id],$arrUpdate);
```